# JavaScript count-up timer

Tags: javascript, html, count

I want to add the count-up timer which will count from specified time.
I want to do this as follows:
I would add the button "reset" and after it's clicked the timer starts and counts forever from that specified time, but if I press it again in the future it counts time from that specified time in the future.

```
var countDownDate = new Date();
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

  // Get todays date and time
  var now = new Date().getTime();

  // Find the distance between now an the count down date
  var distance = countDownDate.getTime() + now;

  // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}, 1000);
```

I have code like this but the output is very wrong.
Here is the  link: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LL9gomde/)

Comment: `countDownDate.getTime() + now;`

Comment: Well it is already like that in my code, as you can check in JSFiddle, it shows big number of days, like it couldn't refresh or reset

Comment: It should be `countDownDate.getTime() - now;`

Comment: I made it to `var distance = now - countDownDate.getTime() ;` and now it starts from 0 but resets everytime I refresh the page, close but still not what I want :)

Comment: Look at `var countDownDate = new Date();`

Comment: It should store somehow the date I start my counter, but to be honest I don't see the solution now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `localStorage` to save the date

```
var countDownDate = localStorage.getItem('startDate');
if (countDownDate) {
    countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate);
} else {
    countDownDate = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
}

// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = now - countDownDate.getTime();

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}, 1000);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5a6ranep/1/

Comment: Works like a charm, but how do I reset the timer?

Comment: @kpitownhall
`countDownDate = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);`

Comment: OK, I got it working but when I change page on the website the counter resets automatically, how to run it in the background all the time?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. If you open the jsfiddle link it should still be counting from the same time you opened it last time.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <body>
   <button onclick="console.log(getTimeElapsed());">Log Time Elapsed</button>
   <script type="application/javascript">  
    var startTime = Date.now(); // Get Starting time in MS
    var endTime = 0;
    var timeElapsed = 0;

    function getTimeElapsed() {
     endTime = Date.now(); // Get current Time
     timeElapsed = endTime - startTime; // current time - startTime = Time Elapsed
     startTime = Date.now();
     
     return timeElapsed * 0.001; // Convert MS to S
    }
   </script>
  </body>
 </html>
```